# Firefox problems with refreshing content on screen

Tags: firefox, 13.10

I had this problem in 13.04 but now in 13.10 this problem is a lot more noticable. When Firefox loads page it sometimes 'forgets' to redraw the screen, so my page stays as it is, and when I hover over some parts of website they start to appear. Sometimes I have to zoom in and out to 'force' Firefox to refresh screen.
Hardware acceleration is turned on but it's the same when I turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start firefox with add-ons disabled. If that works, some add-on is causing it. Otherwise, you may try starting it in safe-mode.

Comment: I don't have these problems in 14.04, thank you

Comment: @Alen I'm facing the similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04